# I can't see the menu of vscode in Ubuntu16 on Virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ide, visual-studio-code

I download the deb file --vscode Version 1.10 , and double it to install in Ubuntu16 Virtualbox5.1, and when i lanch vscode , I can't use it and no menu just black screen
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will necessarily fix your specific problem but I've seen strange UI/graphical glitches arise from having 3D acceleration enabled in VirtualBox. Sometimes switching that off and sticking with 2D resolves the issue. Might be worth a try to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I switch the 3D off, it succeeds.

Comment: Works for me. For me it actually also fixed repeated crashes of the whole VM with memory violations.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround exists. It is possible to run the vscode with 3D option enabled if the app is launched with gpu disabled switch like -

`code --disable-gpu -a`

This has worked in Ubuntu 20 LTS and Linux Mint VMs. This is a well-known bug in Linux VMs when run anything based on Electron. Haven't been resolved as per to date.

[See here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84745) for more details of this bug.